# Mysql триггер - условие WHERE возможно?

Tags: mysql

По данному триггеру ошибка , что не верное условие. Использование WHERE вроде бы возможно. В чем ошибка?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER set_datetime_start BEFORE INSERT ON ft_json 

FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    SET NEW.start_date = NOW() WHERE NEW.counts = 1;

END;

$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: У SET не может быть where https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-variable.html используйте IF

Comment: Но ещё разумнее - установить для поля `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` и не городить костылей на триггерах. Хотя логика происходящего - непонятна... если поле `counts` установлено в единицу, то похерить ввод и установить в поле `start_date` текущие дату-время, иначе оставить как есть (даже если NULL) - ну бред, право слово.

Comment: Да уже решил с дефолтными значениями, что то выпали из головы. И триггер не нужен.